# Save an output file on disk using shell commands in a django app

Tags: python, django, shell

I am creating a script to run shell commands for simulation purposes using a web app. I want to run a `shell` command in a `django` app and then save the output to a file.

The problem I am facing is that when running the `shell` command, the output tries to get saved in the url that is invoked (for example: `localhost:8000/projects`) which is understandable.

I want to save the output to for example:
`/home/myoutput/output.txt` rather than `/projects` or `/tasks`

I have to run a whole script and save it's output to the txt file later but that is easy once this is done.

Tried `os.chdir()` function to change directory to `/desiredpath` already

```py
from subprocess import run

#the function invoked from views.py
def invoke_mpiexec():
  run('echo "this is a test file" > fahadTest.txt')
```

> FileNotFoundError at /projects
>
> Exception Type:   FileNotFoundError

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I want to say that directly calling external programs from a web request in Django is a bit of an anti-pattern. The preferred approach is to use a work queue like [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) or [rq](https://python-rq.org/), but that comes with a bit of added complexity.

That being said, you can solve your problem with the argument `shell=True`:

```
from subprocess import run

#the function invoked from views.py
def invoke_mpiexec():
  run('echo "this is a test file" > fahadTest.txt', shell=True)
```

Here is the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments):

> If shell is True, the specified command will be executed through the
>   shell. This can be useful if you are using Python primarily for the
>   enhanced control flow it offers over most system shells and still want
>   convenient access to other shell features such as shell pipes,
>   filename wildcards, environment variable expansion, and expansion of ~
>   to a user’s home directory. However, note that Python itself offers
>   implementations of many shell-like features (in particular, glob,
>   fnmatch, os.walk(), os.path.expandvars(), os.path.expanduser(), and
>   shutil).

**Note:** Using `shell=True` can lead to [security issues](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#security-considerations):

> If the shell is invoked explicitly, via shell=True, it is the
>   application’s responsibility to ensure that all whitespace and
>   metacharacters are quoted appropriately to avoid shell injection
>   vulnerabilities.

Comment: I already figured it out but loads of thanks for explaining it in a detailed form. And yes I will address the security issues.

Answer (score 0):

You should use **subprocess.call** with **stdout** argument

```
def invoke_mpiexec():
    f = open("fahadTest.txt", "w")
    subprocess.call(['echo', '"this is a test file"'], stdout=f)
```

or use **write** function

```
def invoke_mpiexec():
    f = open('fahadTest.txt', 'w')
    f.write("Now the file has more content!")
    f.close()
```

Comment: I want to do it with pure shell scripting and not file handling system of python

Comment: Ok, you should add shell=True.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out.

Below is the fix:

```py
run('mkdir -p $HOME/phdata/test/ && echo "this is a test file" > $HOME/phdata/test/fahadTest.txt', shell=True)
```

> `mkdir -p creates a directory if it doesn't exist`
>
> `$HOME` is used to go to the home directory and from there you can
>   navigate to folders.
>
> `shell=True` argument is required to run it as shell command

You can also create a ssh connection and run the commands/ scripts on the remote server. For this, my approach will be to create a script on the remote server, call it through my app and provide arguments to it. Another workaround which is not that good but works is to create a script on the server using the above line and then call it.